# Two companies are in danger of failing.( fails),( fails), and ( and  both fail) . What is the probability that  fails and  survives?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

this is a probability question from a Master's course. The scenario is:

Two companies  and  are in danger of failing, analysts reckon that in the next year: ( fails)=0.7, ( fails)=0.6 and ( and  both fail)=0.5 .

1. What is the probability that  fails and  survives?
2. What is the probability that both will survive?

My thoughts so far are:

1-0.5 = 0.5, but that is unlikely to be correct.

Probability that at least one will fail is 0.7+0.6−(0.5)(0.7), but I still do not seem to get the correct answer.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the probability that M fails is $.7$, and the probability that they both fail is $.5$, then the probability that only M fails is $.7-.5=.2$

Comment: Thank you. Is the probability that both survive then 0.3 + 0.4?

Comment: I believe you would need to multiply those probabilities rather than add them.

Comment: According to the problem statement, the correct answer is 0.2 again. But I am not sure how one arrives at that?

Comment: I believe the reasoning is the following: There are four options, either no fails, M fails, H fails, or both fail.  P(both) is given as .5, and we have previously discussed P(M). P(H) can be found in a similar way, and is ".6 - .5 = .1".  The probabilities must add up to 1, so "1 - .5 - .1 - .2 = .2", which gives the final answer as .2 that neither fails. My earlier comment was false.

Answer (score 2):

Do a Venn's diagram and solve it immediately[image]

1. 0.2
2. try by yourself using the above diagram.